# How do I sent an "over-sized" video via my Anrdoid?

Tags: video, email

When I try to e-mail my 10-minute videos to my gmail account, but when I try to attach the videos the phone gives me this error: 'File is too large and cannot be attached'.  Can't reproduce because my Android is hooked up to USB, but I'll edit--

S3x--

What's any convenient way to upload/send a video without having to get out the USB?  Can I do it without using any 3rd-party apps, or at least using safe 3rd-party apps?   Youtube is an option, I believe, but I want to have a hard copy on my PC for editing.  Attachments are more convenient.

Comment: I haven't use email attachments as a file-transfer medium since I started using services such as Dropbox. :)

Comment: I'd like to have a local copy from a site I frequently visit, like gmail.  I'll look at Dropbox, though.  If there's a workaround to get attachments going, like expanding my memory limit, somehow, that would be ideal; however I'll consider this a work around.  Let's try not to get into a long discussion with suggestions about this app and that, though, please.

Comment: Checked out Dropbox.  Looks like 2 gigs free, right off the bat, and an 18 gig limit.  Checked out their license: https://www.dropbox.com/terms.  It's fine.  So, I'd say it's pretty nice.

Comment: @iglzvx Send me a PM or a chat with your referral info, please, or put it here if you want--  Thanks.

Comment: sure thing! 500MB for both of us. Be sure to also check out the "Get Free Space" page on Dropbox for even more space (+ about 1 GB). http://db.tt/owEaAa2e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The majority of web based email providers have a limit of 10MB for the size of the attachment of every message sent.

Since an email message will often pass through several mail transfer agents to reach the recipient, some or probably all of them impose size limits due to the storage capabilities they have to deal with. This is due to the fact that every message needs to be stored before getting forward.

Applications tend to follow this type of ruling. Although nowadays users tend to use an email like if it was an ftp, thus "forcing" application developers to suppress such limits but given no guaranties that the message will in fact get to its destination.

**To resume**, you can safely send files up to 10MB between any email providers without the fear of message not being delivered.

---

My advice to you is the usage of free online services that allow you the transfer or backup of large amount of data between locations:

**No payment and no registration:**

- [wetransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/) (*~2Gb for each transfer*)

**No payment, just registration:** (*for the free package*)

- [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/)
- [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/start#home)
- [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/)
- [yousendit](https://www.yousendit.com/)
- [DropSend](http://www.dropsend.com/)

Comment: Wet trasnfer's pretty good.  thaanks.